# How to parse retrofit json body using gson in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I am working on android app writing in kotlin. I have a issue with json parsing actually i am hitting webservice using retrofit library for pojo i have taken kotlin data class. I am getting success response after that i am trying to parse json response with gson library here i am getting error.

code:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginDataModel>, response: Response<LoginDataModel>) {
    if(response.isSuccessful){
        var loginDataModel = response.body()

        print(loginDataModel)
    }else{}
}
```

model:

```
data class LoginDataModel(var userId: Int, var id: Int, var title: String, var body: String) {}
```

error:

```
fun <T : Any!> fromJson(json: JsonElement!, classOfT: Class<T!>!): T! defined in com.google.gson.Gson
```

Comment: `response.body()` will return `LoginDataModel` directly .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`
 in your retrofit Builder . I believe you will need [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson)
in case you miss the `GsonCOnverterFactory.create()`

and no need there for long parsing.

Example :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

**EDIT** : 
You will also need to annotate your model class with the @  `@SerializedName("jsonKey")` above your variables